# The inner formula of a table touchs a border . How could I fix it

Tags: tables, equations, tabularx, multirow

The code Im using is this,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]\label{tablaequilibrios}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
\hline
Equilibria                &  & X,Y values                                                                                    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.1} &  & $X=0$                                                                                         \\
                          &  & $Y=0$                                                                                         \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.2} &  & $X=k_1$                                                                                       \\
                          &  & $Y=0$                                                                                         \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.3} &  & $X=k_2$                                                                                       \\
                          &  & $Y=0$                                                                                         \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 2}   &  & $X$=$-\frac{\tau}{\phi}$                                                                      \\
                          &  & $Y$=$-\frac{\rho\tau}{K_2\phi}-\rho-\frac{\rho\tau^2}{k_1k_2\phi^2}-\frac{\rho\tau}{k_1\phi}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\caption{Equilibrios del sistema 2-Dimensional}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the last equation the parameter \phi touch the down border of the table, how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with macro `\makecellgapes` you can add vertical space around cells content:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|ll>{$}l<{$}|}
\hline
Equilibria                &  & X,Y \text{ values}   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.1} &  & X=0    \\
                          &  & Y=0    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.2} &  & X=k_1  \\
                          &  & Y=0    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 1.3} &  & X=k_2  \\
                          &  & Y=0    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{CASE 2}   &  & X=-\dfrac{\tau}{\phi}$ \\
                          &  & Y=-\dfrac{\rho\tau}{K_2\phi}
                               -\rho -\dfrac{\rho\tau^2}{k_1k_2\phi^2}
                               - \dfrac{\rho\tau}{k_1\phi} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Equilibrios del sistema 2-Dimensional}
\label{tablaequilibrios}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

note: `\label{...}` had to be after `\caption{...}`, otherwise referencing this table will not be correct.

**edit:**
corrected is the use of the `$` (it was wrong). now the last column is in the "math" mode an therefore all `$` in equations are removed.